# WordPress index.php seems to perform unwanted redirect 301

Tags: redirect, http

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

---

**Configuration:**

1. Debian Jessie
2. Front-end Nginx (1 server, 2 server_names; rewrites working correctly),
3. Proxied back-end Apache with no rewrites/aliases and other,
4. WordPress installed in `/var/www/www.test.blog/wordpress/` with no plugins,
5. No constants declared in `wp-config.php`.

---

**Task:**
I'm trying to make WP being resolved from multiple GET URLs:
`test.blog` and `www.test.blog`.

Due to Apache logs everything goes just fine until requesting reaches `/var/www/www.test.blog/wordpress/index.php` (line:18), after which, suddenly, appears response 301 to `test.blog` (line:19)

```
01:Request received from client: GET /wordpress/ HTTP/1.0
02:Headers received from client:
03:X-Real-IP: 10.0.2.2
04:X-Forwarded-For: 10.0.2.2
05:Host: www.test.blog
06:Connection: close
07:User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
08:Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
09:Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng
10:DNT: 1
11:Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
12:Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
13:authorization result of Require all granted: granted
14:authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
15:request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /wordpress/
16:authorization result of Require all granted: granted
17:authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
18:request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /wordpress/index.php
19:Response sent with status 301, headers:
20:Date: Fri, 26 Jan 2018 14:20:49 GMT
21:Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
22:Location: http://test.blog/wordpress/
23:Content-Length: 0
24:Connection: close
25:Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

---

**Question:**
Can it be that WP itself makes any redirect via PHP? I mean, it's totally capable of it, but does it happen actually <sub>(as I have no other suspects)</sub>?
And if, what should I do to stop this behavior & **finally** make it being resolved from multiple URLs?

Comment: What are Home URL and Site URL set to in the settings?

Comment: This is how WordPress is supposed to work if you've configured rewrite rules in your `nginx.conf` - requests to index.php are redirected and handled by WordPress. Is the redirect resulting in you ending up at the wrong page?

Comment: @swissspidy, they are not set on purpose. I was hoping to prevent WP this way from making own rewrites...

Comment: @phatskat, well, I've not seen anywhere info, saying that WP is intended to make own rewrites. It seems even wrong WP making own "black boxed" rewrites...

Comment: @phatskat, actually, yes, instead of keeping host `www.test.blog`, WP seems to change it to `test.blog`. Also it makes new URL visible, changing it in adress bar... I still get target page, but like `test.blog/wordpress/wp-admin...` instead of requested `www.test.blog/wordpress/wp-admin...`  And it drives me a bit mad, as I didn't want URL to change...only redirected behind the scenes...

Comment: I would follow the advice of @swissspidy and check the values of your home URL and site URL. These values can be found in the `wp_options` table and determine what URL WordPress thinks it lives at. If it think's it's address is `test.blog` and not `www.test.blog` then it will try to redirect to the correct domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like both Home URL and Site URL for your blog are set to `http://test.blog`, while your server accepts both `http://test.blog` and `http://www.test.blog`.

If you access the latter, WordPress will redirect you because of the mismatch. You might be able to set the Home URL and Site URL dynamically in your `wp-config.php` like this:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define( 'WP_HOME',    'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

This way, there shouldn't be a redirect. But this has of course complications for things like URLs in post content. WordPress [does not use relative URLs for that](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/contribute/design-decisions/#absolute-versus-relative-urls). That's why it's generally better to settle one 1 domain. But there are also other reasons like SEO (duplicate content). Your web server should either redirect www.test.blog to test.blog or vice-versa, it's the easiest way to solve this. The site will obviously still be available via either host, it's just that you have to settle for one.

Note: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is not set on the command line, so if you want to use WP-CLI you'd have to set that variable.

Please let me know if that answers your question or if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Yep, seems you're got it even better than I could expect :)   Much obliged for the link you've given, I'll examine the material.  Great thanks for specifying those defines - I'm so clumsy with these global variables...   Seems I really should settle for 1 domain as good practice. I've just got overwhelmed with ideas, while being a total stranger with SEO...